# Parameter typecheck at buildtime in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, typechecking, value-objects

I've the following ValueObject classes to encapsulate IDs:

```js
class UserID {
    constructor(readonly id: number) {}
}

class ProductID {
    constructor(readonly id: number) {}
}
```

And the following function:

```js
function addUser(user : UserID) : Promise<void> {
   //... do stuff
}

const productID = new ProductID(1);
addUser(productID); //<-- This won't trigger any build error :(
```

The compiler will accept `addUser(new ProductID(1))` as a correct statement. I know it's impossible to typecheck this function at runtime due JavaScript "limitations", but why we can't get an error at developement time?

I want typechecking to check function parameter types configurable via `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: In JavaScript we would write `if (user instanceof UserID) { ... }` to check it at runtime...

Comment: I think you want to use `InstanceType<UserID>` over just using `UserID` which is a class, as a type. Also, be sure to turn on strict mode in tsconfig.json